# Combining PostGIS, GeoDjango and OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, openlayers, geodjango

I'm attempting to create a GIS application to display some data onto a OSM map.

I followed the [GeoDjango tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial) to get shapefile WorldBorders data into my Postgis Database, but I am unsure on how I could pull the relevant data into a template for use with OpenLayers.

Any advice on how I may be able to connect this data with OpenLayers?  I've looked around but can't find anything concrete on how to do this, asides from using GeoServer but I would rather stick with my current stack if possible.

Comment: which geodjango tutorial did you follow? can you post the link

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer your question to need to mine comments for critical information.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this answer will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034482/rendering-spatial-data-of-geoqueryset-in-a-custom-view-on-geodjango?answertab=votes#tab-top

> **Consuming Data**
>
> OpenLayers has 'format' objects which can read data: There are formats
>   for GeoJSON and KML, as well as others.
>
> You can load the data using standard XMLHttpRequest mechanisms then
>   parse them with a format:
>
> var f = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(); var features =
>   f.read(req.responseText); layer.addFeatures(features);
>
> Alternatively, you can use the built in Protocol support to load
>   remote data:
>
> ```
>  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
>  var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
>      "OpenLayers WMS", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0",
>      {layers: 'basic'}
>  );
>
>  var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
>      strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
>      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
>         url: "/django/view/json/",
>         format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
>      })
>  });
>
>  map.addLayers([wms, layer]);
>  map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(
>      -3.92, 44.34, 4.87, 49.55
>  ));
> ```
>
> You can see in this example, that the 'url' points to your Django
>   view; all the loading of data and parsing it according to the provided
>   format is included. (You can see a similar example in the OpenLayers
>   example for fixed behavior/http protocol.) Putting it Together
>
> ```
> Create a Django view, using vectorformats to return your data as GeoJSON
> Create a separate view, which returns an HTML page like the OpenLayers example linked, with the modifications shown in the code
> ```
>
> sample.
>       That view serves the HTML page that loads your GeoJSON data and parses it.